# How to switch back from ImageMapType to normal map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am not sure how to switch back from ImageMapType to normal map. The problem is described in code as followings (pseudo code):

```
    var myMap;
    var curLabLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(36.415793, -121.084421);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 21,
      streetViewControl: false,
      center: curLabLocation,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.MAP
    };
    var $map = $('#map-canvas');

    myMap = new google.maps.Map($map[0], mapOptions);


    // A) Switch to image type map. NO problem
    var imageMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
      getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
          // Simply empty. How to delete this????? After B)
          // this function still working, which prevent
          // normal map to show up.
          return null;
      },
      tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),

      maxZoom: 23,
      minZoom: 22,
      name: 'image type map'
    });


    myMap.mapTypes.set('imagetypemap', imageMapType);
    myMap.setMapTypeId('imagetypemap');

   // Now, it works fine with ImageMapType.


   // B) Switch back to normal map. Problem is the map is empty due
   // to getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {} still working.
   myMap.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.MAP);

   // I tried this. But not working. myMap.overlayMapTypes.length=0   before clear() is called. So, this is not right way to clear ImageMapType.

   myMap.overlayMapTypes.clear();
   myMap.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.MAP);
```

Do I need to re-create the map object? Is there way not to re-create the map object? If no, how to do it?

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it helped you. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

`google.maps.MapTypeId.MAP` is undefined, the built-in MapTypeIds are

- `google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID`
- `google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP`
- `google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE`
- `google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN`

Demo:

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
    zoom: 1,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControl:false,
    mapTypeIds:[google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP],
    noClear:true
  }),
  btn=document.getElementById('mt');
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(btn);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(btn,'click',function(){
       map.setMapTypeId((this.value==='moon')
                          ? 'moon'
                          : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
                          
 });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map,'maptypeid_changed',function(){
       btn.value=(this.getMapTypeId()==='moon')
                  ?'earth'
                  :'moon'
  });
  var moonMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
        var normalizedCoord = getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom);
        if (!normalizedCoord) {
          return null;
        }
        var bound = Math.pow(2, zoom);
        return 'http://mw1.google.com/mw-planetary/lunar/lunarmaps_v1/clem_bw' +
            '/' + zoom + '/' + normalizedCoord.x + '/' +
            (bound - normalizedCoord.y - 1) + '.jpg';
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    maxZoom: 9,
    minZoom: 0,
    radius: 1738000,
    name: 'Moon'
  });

  map.mapTypes.set('moon', moonMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId('moon');
}

// Normalizes the coords that tiles repeat across the x axis (horizontally)
// like the standard Google map tiles.
function getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom) {
  var y = coord.y;
  var x = coord.x;

  // tile range in one direction range is dependent on zoom level
  // 0 = 1 tile, 1 = 2 tiles, 2 = 4 tiles, 3 = 8 tiles, etc
  var tileRange = 1 << zoom;

  // don't repeat across y-axis (vertically)
  if (y < 0 || y >= tileRange) {
    return null;
  }

  // repeat across x-axis
  if (x < 0 || x >= tileRange) {
    x = (x % tileRange + tileRange) % tileRange;
  }

  return {x: x, y: y};
}
```

```css
html, body,#map {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
<div id="map"><input type="button" id="mt"></div>
<script async defer  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=initMap"></script>
```

---

### `<edit/>`

The source of the problem seems to be an internal function which calculates the minZoom/maxZoom for the map(not the maptypes), e.g. to create the zoom-control. When the minZoom/maxZoom-ranges of both mapTypes not intersect the issue occurs.

a possible fix: execute the following code somewhere(before you create a map).
It overrides the built-in Map-method  `setMapTypeId`.
Initially it removes the minZoom/maxZoom-values of the mapTypes and stores them in another object. When a mapType will be set first the minZoom/maxZoom-values of the Map(if there are any) will be discarded, and after setting the new mapType the minZoom/maxZoom of the Map will be set based on the stored settings of the mapType.

```
(
    function(gm){
      var f=gm.prototype.setMapTypeId;
      gm.prototype.setMapTypeId=function(t){
        if(this.mapTypes){
          var that  = this,
              mt    = this.mapTypes.get(t);
              zr    = {minZoom:null,maxZoom:null};
          if(!mt.get('zr')){
            for(var k in zr){
              zr[k]=mt[k]||null;
              delete mt[k];
            }
            mt.set('zr',zr);
          }
          that.setValues({minZoom:null,maxZoom:null});
          f.call(this,t);
          that.setValues(mt.get('zr'));
        }
      }
    }(google.maps.Map)
  );
```

**Demo:**

```js
function initMap() {

  (
    function(gm){
      var f=gm.prototype.setMapTypeId;
      gm.prototype.setMapTypeId=function(t){
        if(this.mapTypes){
          var that  = this,
              mt    = this.mapTypes.get(t);
              zr    = {minZoom:null,maxZoom:null};
          if(!mt.get('zr')){
            for(var k in zr){
              zr[k]=mt[k]||null;
              delete mt[k];
              
            }
            mt.set('zr',zr);
          }
          that.setValues({minZoom:null,maxZoom:null});
          f.call(this,t);
          that.setValues(mt.get('zr'));
        }
      }
    }(google.maps.Map)
  );
  
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
    zoom: 1,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControl:false,
    mapTypeIds:[google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP],
    noClear:true
  }),
  btn=document.getElementById('mt');
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(btn);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(btn,'click',function(){
       map.setMapTypeId((this.value==='moon')
                          ? 'moon'
                          : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
                          
 });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map,'maptypeid_changed',function(){
       btn.value=(this.getMapTypeId()==='moon')
                  ?'earth'
                  :'moon'
  });
  var moonMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
        var normalizedCoord = getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom);
        if (!normalizedCoord) {
          return null;
        }
        var bound = Math.pow(2, zoom);
        return 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA4e2.jpg?s=256&g=1';
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    maxZoom: 23,
    minZoom: 22,
    radius: 1738000,
    name: 'Moon'
  });

  map.mapTypes.set('moon', moonMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId('moon');
}

// Normalizes the coords that tiles repeat across the x axis (horizontally)
// like the standard Google map tiles.
function getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom) {
  var y = coord.y;
  var x = coord.x;

  // tile range in one direction range is dependent on zoom level
  // 0 = 1 tile, 1 = 2 tiles, 2 = 4 tiles, 3 = 8 tiles, etc
  var tileRange = 1 << zoom;

  // don't repeat across y-axis (vertically)
  if (y < 0 || y >= tileRange) {
    return null;
  }

  // repeat across x-axis
  if (x < 0 || x >= tileRange) {
    x = (x % tileRange + tileRange) % tileRange;
  }

  return {x: x, y: y};
}
```

```css
html, body,#map {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
<div id="map"><input type="button" id="mt"></div>
<script async defer  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=initMap"></script>
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#MapTypeId

Comment: I tried google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, but get 'Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded' error, and infinite loop. I tried to solve the infinite loop problem for a while, I find google.maps.MapTypeId.MAP is the only way to switch back. But, map does not display due to getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom){} still active. May be question is how to remove getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom){}

Comment: There is no issue for me with setting a built-in MaptypeId (added a demo to my answer)

Comment: Mine still have problem, possibly due to I am drawing a lot of objects on map. I will use yours as starting point to figure out what is the problem. Thank you very much for your detailed post.

Comment: ImageMapType ,     maxZoom: 23,      minZoom: 22, causes problem of 'Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded'

Comment: But, I need these zoom number after switching to ImageMapType map, in order for drawing rectangle with correct size. So, my problem is not fully solved yet. maxZoom:9, minZoom:0 does not cause problem, but rectangle does not draw correctly, which suppose to be drawn with zoom>21.

Comment: Thank you for your posting. "earth' map does not show after adding that function

Comment: you don't see the earth-map when you run the 2nd code-snippet?

Comment: Yes. I added the function. Earth map is gone. Your demo is same.

Comment: Click 'earth', then, no map show up. Just blue. I also tried the code in my project, worked, but now map show up.

Comment: zoom out, the blue is water

Comment: I solved my problem. I need to put the function after the creation of map object. Thank you very much for your help!!!